# Differentiation of fractions of negative powers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I tried differentiating a particular equation
$y=1/(-x)^2  $
And got two answers using two mathematically correct solutions. I need to know which is correct and why.

Method 1:
Simplifying $y=1/(-x)^2$ to $y=1/x^2$and using chain rule with a $u=x$ $dy/dx = -2/x^3$

Method 2:
Just using chain rule with $u=-x$ $dy/dx = 2/(-x)^3$

Comment: Both are correct

Comment: Thanks, just saw understood the real issue here

Comment: you're werlcome Solvitron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But $-\dfrac{2}{x^3}=\dfrac{2}{(-x)^3}$